# Sequelize belongs to many get and post request

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have belongs to many associations of the model Technology and Project. At the same time, on the client, I have two tables, free technologies and technologies on the project. Please tell me (or suggest how to do it) how to make a get request for all free technologies and a post request to add them to the table on the project. I figured out all the associations, but stopped at this one. I will be grateful for any help.

**models/Project.js**

```
const {
  Model
} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Project extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      Project.hasMany(models.Role, { foreignKey: "projectId", as: "roles" });
      Project.belongsToMany(models.Technology, { foreignKey: "projectId", through: "ProjectsTechnologies"});
    }
  };
  Project.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    image: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "Project",
  });
  return Project;
};
```

**models/Technology.js**

```
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Technology extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      Technology.belongsToMany(models.Project, { foreignKey: "technologyId", through: "ProjectsTechnologies"});
    }
  }
  Technology.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Technology',
  });
  return Technology;
};
```

***models/ProjectsTechs**

```
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class ProjectsTechnologies extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      ProjectsTechnologies.belongsTo(models.Project, {foreignKey: "projectId"});
      ProjectsTechnologies.belongsTo(models.Technology, {foreignKey: "technologyId"});
    }
  };
  ProjectsTechnologies.init({
    projectId: DataTypes.STRING,
    technologyId: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'ProjectsTechnologies',
  });
  return ProjectsTechnologies;
};
```

Currently I'm doing this get request for get all free technologies

```
router.get("/techologies", async (req, res) => {
  const listOfTech = await Technology.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Project,
        as: "projects",
        through: {
          model: ProjectsTechnologies
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  res.json(listOfTech);
});
```

And post req for posting technologies in "On project" table

```
router.post("/create/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const technology = await ProjectsTechnologies.create(req.body);
  const project = await Project.findOne({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id
    }
  });
  res.json(technology);
});
```

I also keep trying to do it differently, because these options don't seem right to me.

Comment: What does it mean `free technologies`?

Comment: All available technologies that not used on this project.

Comment: For that you need to add a subquery in conditions for `Technology`

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for this advice. But I'm new to this. I tried to solve the problem with your advice. But it doesn't work. Now I do it like this `router.get("/techologies", async (req, res) => {
  const listOfTech = await Technology.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: Project,
        as: "projects",
        through: {
          model: ProjectsTechnologies
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  res.json(listOfTech);
});
`

Comment: `router.post("/create/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const technology = await ProjectsTechnologies.create(req.body);
  const project = await Project.findOne({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id
    }
  });
  res.json(technology);
}); `

Comment: Please correct your post with all this. It's hard to read  code in comments

Comment: Sorry for this unreadable comments. I add my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query a list of technologies that are not used in any of projects you need to use a subquery in `where` option:

```js
const listOfTech = await Technology.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.literal('NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `ProjectsTechnologies` where `ProjectsTechnologies`.`technologyId`=`Technology`.`id`)')
  });
```